# Gazebo is not opening

Tags: 14.04

I am working in Ubuntu 14.04.4.

I just install the gazebo5. Neither the gazebo is launching nor it shows some error.

What is the problem then ??

Comment: Have you try to run it from command line? Have you check the logs?

Comment: Yes I run in command line..  I am a beginner I dont know how to check logs.

Comment: I just checked the logs and there isn't mentioned about gazebo on the logs.

Comment: So when you launch it from the command line, the command line remains empty afterwards and no window appears? There is really nothing in the command line at all?

Comment: @potAito yes no window appears. .

Comment: I check something. Actually I have hybrid graphics. It shows nothing on AMD M370 graphics. when I switch to Intel (built-in) graphics. The scenario is same.                                                                                                    
         Last day I had ubuntu 14.04.5 and gazebo was working. but due to AMD graphics card I switched to 14.04.4. Now gazebo is not working –.

Answer (score 3):

Even though it is a old question, I am answering for the sake of other people who end up here looking for a solution to a similar question.

I too got the same problem, then I ran `gazebo --verbose`, then I got an error message saying that another Gazebo process is running.

I then killed the gzserver process by `killall gzserver`. Then it started working fine.